# Ошибка при получении данных с сайта с помощью библиотеки requests

Tags: python, requests

путаюсь получить данные с сайта с помощью библиотеки requests с помощью данного кода:

```
import requests
req = requests.get("https://henderson.ru")
src = req.text
print(src)
```

выходит следующая ошибка:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='henderson.ru', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)')))
```

пытаюсь ее исправить с помощью приписки в код параметра verify=False:

```
import requests
req = requests.get("https://henderson.ru", verify=False)
src = req.text
print(src)
```

Вылетает другая ошибка:

```
InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host 'henderson.ru'. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/1.26.x/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  warnings.warn
```

Кто сталкивался с этим или знает, как это исправить, подскажите, пожалуйста

Comment: `Вылетает другая ошибка:` - это не ошибка, это предупреждение, из-за того что вы проверку сертификата отключили.

Comment: но если это предупреждение, почему тогда в переменной src нет данных сайта? как получить эти данные?

Comment: Нужно смотреть, что приходит в переменную и разбираться. Вы только предупреждение привели в вопросе.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

 

    <meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer" />

    <script src="/__qrator/qauth_utm_v2_ve354.js"></script>

 

</head>

<body>

 

</body>

</html>

Comment: Это все что туда приходит

Comment: Значит сайт загружается динамически (js скриптом), смотрите в сторону Selenium

Comment: спасибо, посмотрю, как он загружается